# Using a black square as list icon: How to position it correctly?

Tags: xetex, positioning, enumerate, fontsize

I would like to use a black square ■ instead of the standard bullet • for lists. Now its default size is a bit too big for my taste, so I shrank it down and ended up with the following definition (MWE below):

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{{\tiny $■$}}
```

Unfortunately, this will make the baselines of the square and the following list item align, i.e. the square will not be centered vertically with respect to the following text. How do I fix this? Any help would be much appreciated!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\tiny $■$}


\begin{document}

Some sample text

\begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With use of the `enumitem` package and defined square by `\rule`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\rule[0.5ex]{0.6ex}{0.6ex}}


\begin{document}

Some sample text

\begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I adopted an another strategy using into `\labelitemi`, the option `\raisebox{.25\height}` where it is possible to move up or down the position of the little `\blacksquare` symbol. The choice of the position depends of the value of `.25`: if this number is positive the blacksquare will go upwards. If this number is negative it will go downwards. Here there is a MWE with the screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raisebox{.25\height}{\tiny$\blacksquare$}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent \lipsum[1][2-3]

\begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[1][3-4]
  \item \lipsum[1][5-6]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, `\raiseheight` was the command I was looking for! I had been googling for quite a while. :)

Comment: @balu So I have read your mind with my crystal ball...:-)))))