# Reproduction of a paper for the state exam in Italy

Tags: pdftex, mtpro, newtx, structure, calligra

- I apologize so much to you for not even having the time to go to the
  bathroom but I ask you a humble courtesy. This is also the reason why I am more or less absent from TeX.SE :(.
- During the afternoon it was announced that the second test of the state exam concluding the course of study of Mathematics is the responsibility of the internal
  commissioner, see [here](https://www.orizzontescuola.it/maturita-2022-scarica-la-bozza-di-ordinanza-torna-la-prova-scritta-di-italiano-e-la-seconda-di-indirizzo-poi-il-colloquio-si-parte-il-22-giugno/)
- I am a Math and Physics committee teacher.
- The latest title page going back to 2019 can be seen [here](https://www.istruzione.it/esame_di_stato/201819/Licei/Ordinaria/AB02_ORD19.pdf).

[image]

**Question:** I am asking someone of good kindness will to be able to **reproduce just a basic outline** where the **text is in calligraphy** and the **textual font with Times**. **Without QR code** and **without** the **watermark**, where I can possibly create with images or without images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's even legal to reproduce that header for private purposes.

Comment: @egreg Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii :-) It is an exam of state. I think that the answer is yes. The first test in Italian has the same heading and is common. The second test must be written by the Mathematics and Physics teacher of the commission. I believe in the uniformity of the two tests in the state exam.

Comment: +1 for emotional support.

Comment: Maybe set a bounty to increase motivation.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you so much for your kindness. May the good Lord always grant you good health and the best of hopes. I have thought to put a bounty to increase motivation but now it is impossible. I can give additional votes in the meantime. I'm connecting very little now and am always anxiously rushing through every minute.

Comment: I'm sure it is not legal to reproduce the Italian Republic logo on a self-made document.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Hi, if it is for the logo you can remove it is not important. I am just upset about the sudden mode that I did not expect and I am sympathetic to the students.

Comment: I can later today (I am in US timezone and in the office right now) try to help but for that I would need a bit more information what you want.

Comment: @egreg If it is only illegal for the logo it can be removed. I have to customize it myself.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You're fantastic. No hurry I vote everyone ahahahhahah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is my modest attempt to help you out. This is clearly not a "clean" solution but hopefully, it motivates others to improve on it.**

- Please carefully read the comments in the code.
- I use a picture for the calligraphy text since it is the same text on all pages. I guess that this makes it easier. You can create the calligraphy text outside of LaTeX, e. g. MS WORD and export it as a PDF (and then crop it with some PDF software).
- The calligraphy text is positioned using `tikz` with the `overlay, remember picture` option. I placed the `tikz` code in the footer but it does not matter where you put it as long it is in the footer or header.
- I use the `enumitem` to modify the `itemize` stuff, i. e. larger vertical space and square instead of a circle.
- I did not try to replicate the positioning of the diagram that is on the right side on the first page because I do not how to do that (never user [wrapfig](https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig)). But maybe you can have the diagram "normally" placed like a normal figure.
- Be aware of the `\label{myLastPage}` right before `\end{document}`. This is used to create the '4' in "Page 1 of 4".
- I did not have time to look into the `mtpro` topic, instead, I use `newtxmath` in the code below.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    % showframe is very helpful!
    showframe = true,
    left = 15mm,
    right = 15mm,
    headheight = 20mm,
    headsep = 15mm,
    top = 40mm, % top = headheight + headsep (or larger)
]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

% Remove "demo" option when using actual graphics.
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{enumitem}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529287
\setlist[itemize]{
    label = \rule[0.5ex]{0.6ex}{0.6ex},
    itemsep = 2ex,
    }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

%% Head
% Left
% Label for "myLastPage" is right before "\end{document}".
% I adjust "\\[5mm]" manually until it looks good.
\lhead{Page \thepage/\pageref{myLastPage}\\[5mm]}
% Center
\chead{
    \includegraphics[height = 15mm, width = 15mm]{Logo.png}
    }
% Right
\rhead{
    \includegraphics[height = 15mm, width = 15mm]{QRCode.png}
    % Freely position the next next to the QR code.
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node at (current page.north east) [anchor = north east, align = left, yshift = -8mm, xshift = -35mm] {Sessione ordinaria 2019\\[1ex] Seconda prova scritta};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

%% Foot
% Left
\lfoot{}
% Center
% tikz picture with overlay option. 
% This could be placed in "\chead" as well.
\cfoot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Play with the "yshift" until the "CalligraphyText.pdf" loosk good.
    % Don't forget to activate "showframe = true" in the preamble.
    % You can create "CalligraphyText.pdf" outside of this document, e. g. in MS Word.
    \node at (current page.north) [anchor = north, yshift = -25mm] {
        \includegraphics[height = 10mm, width = 120mm]{CalligraphyText.pdf}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
% Right
\rfoot{}

\begin{document}

%% Page-one specific Stuff
\begin{center}
    {\large%
    \underline{\textbf{ESAME DI STATO DI ISTRUZIONE SECONDARIA SUPERIORE}}%
    }\\[1em]
    %
    \textbf{Indirizzi:} LI02, EA02 -- SCIENTIFICO\\
LI03 -- SCIENTIFICO -- OPZIONE SCIENZE APPLICATE\\
LI15 -- SCIENTIFICO -- SEZIONE AD INDIRIZZO SPORTIVO\\
%
    \textbf{(Testo valevole anche per le corrispondenti sperimentazioni internazionali e quadriennali)}\\[1em]
    %
    \textbf{Tema di:} MATEMATICA e FISICA
\end{center}
\textbf{Il candidato risolva uno dei due problemi e risponda a 4 quesiti.}

%% Problema 1
\section*{Problema 1}
Si considerino le seguenti funzioni:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = ax^2 - x + b \qquad \qquad  g(x) = (ax + b)e^{2x-x^2}  
\end{equation*}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Provare che, comunque siano [...]
    \item Si assuma, d’ora in avanti [...]
    \item Si supponga che nel riferimento [...]
\end{itemize}

\clearpage

%% Problema 2
\section*{Problema 2}
Si considerino le seguenti funzioni:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = ax^2 - x + b \qquad \qquad  g(x) = (ax + b)e^{2x-x^2}  
\end{equation*}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Provare che, comunque siano [...]
    \item Si assuma, d’ora in avanti [...]
    \item Si supponga che nel riferimento [...]
\end{itemize}

% Important
\label{myLastPage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

### Update: calligra

Here is an update using the [`calligra` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fundus-calligra).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    % showframe is very helpful!
    showframe = true,
    left = 15mm,
    right = 15mm,
    headheight = 20mm,
    headsep = 15mm,
    top = 40mm, % top = headheight + headsep (or larger)
]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{calligra}

% Remove "demo" option when using actual graphics.
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{enumitem}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529287
\setlist[itemize]{
    label = \rule[0.5ex]{0.6ex}{0.6ex},
    itemsep = 2ex,
    }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

%% Head
% Left
% Label for "myLastPage" is right before "\end{document}".
% I adjust "\\[5mm]" manually until it looks good.
\lhead{Page \thepage/\pageref{myLastPage}\\[5mm]}
% Center
\chead{
    \includegraphics[height = 15mm, width = 15mm]{Logo.png}
    }
% Right
\rhead{
    \includegraphics[height = 15mm, width = 15mm]{QRCode.png}
    % Freely position the next next to the QR code.
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node at (current page.north east) [anchor = north east, align = left, yshift = -8mm, xshift = -35mm] {Sessione ordinaria 2019\\[1ex] Seconda prova scritta};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

%% Foot
% Left
\lfoot{}
% Center
% tikz picture with overlay option. 
% This could be placed in "\chead" as well.
\cfoot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Play with the "yshift" until the "CalligraphyText.pdf" loosk good.
    % Don't forget to activate "showframe = true" in the preamble.
    % You can create "CalligraphyText.pdf" outside of this document, e. g. in MS Word.
%   \node at (current page.north) [anchor = north, yshift = -25mm] {
%       \includegraphics[height = 10mm, width = 120mm]{CalligraphyText.pdf}
%   };
    \node at (current page.north) [anchor = north, yshift = -25mm] {
        \LARGE \calligra Ministero dell’Istruzione, dell’ Università e della Ricerca
    };  
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
% Right
\rfoot{}

\begin{document}

%% Page-one specific Stuff
\begin{center}
    {\large%
    \underline{\textbf{ESAME DI STATO DI ISTRUZIONE SECONDARIA SUPERIORE}}%
    }\\[1em]
    %
    \textbf{Indirizzi:} LI02, EA02 -- SCIENTIFICO\\
LI03 -- SCIENTIFICO -- OPZIONE SCIENZE APPLICATE\\
LI15 -- SCIENTIFICO -- SEZIONE AD INDIRIZZO SPORTIVO\\
%
    \textbf{(Testo valevole anche per le corrispondenti sperimentazioni internazionali e quadriennali)}\\[1em]
    %
    \textbf{Tema di:} MATEMATICA e FISICA
\end{center}
\textbf{Il candidato risolva uno dei due problemi e risponda a 4 quesiti.}

%% Problema 1
\section*{Problema 1}
Si considerino le seguenti funzioni:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = ax^2 - x + b \qquad \qquad  g(x) = (ax + b)e^{2x-x^2}  
\end{equation*}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Provare che, comunque siano [...]
    \item Si assuma, d’ora in avanti [...]
    \item Si supponga che nel riferimento [...]
\end{itemize}

\clearpage

%% Problema 2
\section*{Problema 2}
Si considerino le seguenti funzioni:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = ax^2 - x + b \qquad \qquad  g(x) = (ax + b)e^{2x-x^2}  
\end{equation*}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Provare che, comunque siano [...]
    \item Si assuma, d’ora in avanti [...]
    \item Si supponga che nel riferimento [...]
\end{itemize}

% Important
\label{myLastPage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thank you with much esteem and sincere affection.